# Select different HDD registry from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, regedit

I've written a simple batch file to make changes to the registry in Windows8, it works as I expected whilst running in Windows8 but now I want to run it from command prompt on a different drive letter.

Booting in recovery mode on my laptop boots to dirve letter X: which gives me access to the command prompt. I have my batch file on an external pen drive on letter D:. I can switch to drive d and run the script but obviously it doesn't know to look on drive letter C: for the registry, I presume it just tries on its current drive letter D:.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\DummyTree]
"Value"="Some String"
```

The above is a sample of the code im trying to run from the pendrive (drive D:) on the main HDD (drive C:).

Comment: @Mike: The best thing to do about that is to edit the post.

Comment: @Mike firstly Mike, I'm not a dude. Secondly poking fun at my spelling when I have dyslexia is not 'cool dude' so if you can't help with the question then please do not poke fun at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying the `regedit.exe` in the C: drive

```
C:\Windows\regedit.exe /s yourregfile.reg
```